# How to compile a python chat program to an exe?

Tags: python-2.7, chat

Well this is a code for the "host" of a two way chatroom. The client's code is very similar. I have tried to compile both of them into an exe with various ways and none of them had a nice result. The exe simply doesnt run. I got all modules, i've tried many codes( many adding the dll files etc into the program too.) I try to compile it as a pyw since it has graphics inside. There is one more py file that has some more info that those two (client and host) pyw files get somehow, but they can still run without it with python.exe .  I dont know how can I help you understand so let me know if you got any questions. Thanks in advance.

This is the host in python 2.7 code:

```
import thread
from ChatFns import *



#---------------------------------------------------#
#---------INITIALIZE CONNECTION VARIABLES-----------#
#---------------------------------------------------#
#Initiate socket and bind port to host PC
WindowTitle = 'Chat - Host User'
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = gethostname()
PORT = 8000
conn = ''
s.bind((HOST, PORT))



#---------------------------------------------------#
#------------------ MOUSE EVENTS -------------------#
#---------------------------------------------------#
def ClickAction():
    #Write message to chat window
    EntryText = FilteredMessage(EntryBox.get("0.0",END))
    LoadMyEntry(ChatLog, EntryText)

    #Scroll to the bottom of chat windows
    ChatLog.yview(END)

    #Erace previous message in Entry Box
    EntryBox.delete("0.0",END)

    #Send my mesage to all others
    conn.sendall(EntryText)





#---------------------------------------------------#
#----------------- KEYBOARD EVENTS -----------------#
#---------------------------------------------------#
def PressAction(event):
    EntryBox.config(state=NORMAL)
    ClickAction()
def DisableEntry(event):
    EntryBox.config(state=DISABLED)




#---------------------------------------------------#
#-----------------GRAPHICS MANAGEMENT---------------#
#---------------------------------------------------#

#Create a window
base = Tk()
base.title(WindowTitle)
base.geometry("400x470")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

#Create a Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
ChatLog.insert(END, "Waiting for client user to connect...\n")
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

#Bind a scrollbar to the Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

#Create the Button to send message
SendButton = Button(base, font=30, text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#E6E6E6", activebackground="#FA5858",
                    command=ClickAction)

#Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
EntryBox.bind("<Return>", DisableEntry)
EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", PressAction)

#Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376,y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6,y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=60, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=60)



#---------------------------------------------------#
#----------------CONNECTION MANAGEMENT--------------#
#---------------------------------------------------#
def GetConnected():
    s.listen(1)
    global conn
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    LoadConnectionInfo(ChatLog, 'Connected with: ' + str(addr) + '\n---------------------------------------------------------------')

    while 1:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            LoadOtherEntry(ChatLog, data)
            if base.focus_get() == None:
                FlashMyWindow(WindowTitle)
                playsound('notif.wav')
        except:
            LoadConnectionInfo(ChatLog, '\n [ User disconnected. ]\n [ Waiting for them to connect...] \n  ')
            GetConnected()

    conn.close()

thread.start_new_thread(GetConnected,())
```

base.mainloop()

Comment: "I have tried to compile both of them into an exe with various ways and none of them had a nice result."  What did you try?  Would you edit the answer to that into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Python is an interpreted language, it's not supposed to be compiled into an .exe file. However, there are tools like **http://py2exe.org/** that create an executable file with Python, strapping the interpreter itself into the file.